# How "connected mode" works in Sonar Lint

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

The below text from sonarLint site

> Connected Mode
>
> With version 2.0+ you can now establish a connection to a SonarQube
>   server (4.5.4+) and bind your Eclipse project to a SonarQube project.
>   This operation will make SonarLint use the analyzers, quality profiles
>   and settings defined on your SonarQube server.
>
> First step is to connect to your SonarQube server: In SonarQube server
>   view, right click and choose "New -> Server connection", or directly
>   do "File -> New -> Other... -> SonarLint -> New Server".
>
> Complete connection details (URL and credentials).
>
> Test connection
>
> Click "Finish" to close the wizard and start updating configuration
>   from the server (may take a while)

After doing these steps we should be able to use the use the sonar qube quality profiles in Eclipse IDE.
But its not showing any violations and issues as warnings
Can anyone help me how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Issues are displayed into *SonarLint Issues* view, example for Eclipse IDE:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other... -> SonarLint -> SonarLint Issues
```

Comment: Did you try to reinstall plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click in the *SonarQube Server* view on your server name > *Update all project bindings*. This way the rules and configurations will be updated to your local analyzer.

After that you can unbind the project and the issues will be listed into *SonarLint Issues* view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting you're not running the analysis.
For issues to show up in error list, you need to analyze/ build your project once you're done configuring SonarLint.

Hope this helps.